# Wicket: repainting textfields and keeping user input

Tags: wicket, textfield, repaint

I'm making a form where a teacher creates questions. One type of question is a multiple choice question. The form has a textArea where you write the question formulation and a listView with textFields for the alternatives.

There is a button to add a new alternative (add a new textField), and when pressed it repaints all the alternatives and adds a new one. Now here's the problem: I want the textfields already in the listView with text in them to keep text written by the teacher after the repaint, but I have no idea how to make this possible (except for saving the values to the database before every repaint, but that seem like a bad idea).

Here's the code for my MultipleChoiceQuestionPanel, I hope it will be sufficient.

```
public class MultiChoiceQuestionPanel extends QuestionPanel {

    private List<Alternative> alternatives;

    @SpringBean
    private AlternativeRepository alternativeRepository;

    public List<Alternative> getAlternatives(){
        return alternatives;
    }

    public MultiChoiceQuestionPanel(String id, MultipleChoiceQuestion q){
        super(id, q);

        final WebMarkupContainer parent = new WebMarkupContainer("alternativesContainer");
        parent.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(parent);
        parent.add(new Label("AnswerLabel", "Svar"));

        q.setAlternatives(alternativeRepository.findByMultipleChoiceQuestion(q));
        alternatives = q.getAlternatives();
        Form form = new Form("addForm");
        form.add(new ListView<Alternative>("alternatives", alternatives) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Alternative> alternativeListItem) {
                alternativeListItem.add((TextField<String>) new TextField<String>("alternative", new AlternativeModel(alternativeListItem.getModelObject())).setRequired(true).setType(String.class));
                Form form = new Form("removeForm");
                form.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("remove") {
                    @Override
                    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                        Alternative selected = alternativeListItem.getModelObject();
                        alternativeRepository.delete(selected);
                        getAlternatives().remove(selected);
                        target.addComponent(parent);
                    }
                });
                alternativeListItem.add(form);
                add(alternativeListItem);
            }
        });

        AjaxSubmitLink a = new AjaxSubmitLink("add") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                Alternative alternative = new Alternative();
                MultipleChoiceQuestion mcq = (MultipleChoiceQuestion) getQuestion();
                alternative.setSequenceNumber(mcq.getAlternatives().size());
                alternative.setMultipleChoiceQuestion((MultipleChoiceQuestion) getQuestion());
                alternativeRepository.save(alternative);
                getAlternatives().add(alternative);
                target.addComponent(parent);
            }
        };
        a.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
        form.add(a);
        parent.add(form);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Javadoc of ListView](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.4.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html):

> WARNING: though you can nest ListViews within Forms, you HAVE to set
>   the setReuseItems property to true in order to have validation work
>   properly. By default, setReuseItems is false, which has the effect
>   that ListView replaces all child components by new instances. The idea
>   behind this is that you always render the fresh data, and as people
>   usually use ListViews for displaying read-only lists (at least, that's
>   what we think), this is good default behavior.
>
> However, as the
>   components are replaced before the rendering starts, the search for
>   specific messages for these components fails as they are replaced with
>   other instances. Another problem is that 'wrong' user input is kept as
>   (temporary) instance data of the components. As these components are
>   replaced by new ones, your user will never see the wrong data when
>   setReuseItems is false.

That's essentially what happens here. You'll have to setReuseItems to true for your ListView.

Comment: This seem to have created a new problem though.
Adding new textFields works perfectly, but my remove button is behaving strange now. Whichever remove button I press, it's the text of the last textField that dissapears, not the text in the textField I remove. Any explanations/suggestions to why that is?

Comment: @LeoSundholm This *seems* to happen a) because you don't refresh the ListView but only certain ListItems and b) because you don't use a Model for your List. You could try to construct your ListView as new ListView<Alternative>("alternatives", new PropertyModel<Alternative>(this, "alternatives"))